# Angular image modal popup

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I should create a pop up that opens after clicking on an image and displays that image bigger. But I get the url instead of the image. I used bootstrap's ngbModal

Details.component.html

```
<img src="{{sku.imageLink}}" (click)="open(sku.imageLink)" style="width: 50%; margin-right: 100px; margin-left: 10%; cursor: pointer;" alt=""     >
```

Details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsService } from 'app/core/services/products.service';
import { Products,Product } from 'app/shared/model/products-model';
import { PopUpComponent } from '../pop-up/pop-up.component';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'lpr-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.scss']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  sku: any;
  subCategory: Product;
  data: any={};
  quantity: number=1;
  i=1;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductsService,
    private dialogRef: MatDialog,
    private modalService: NgbModal

  ) { 
    this.sku=this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('sku')
    console.log(this.sku)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProductbySku()
  }

  getProductbySku(){
    this.productService.getProductsBySku(this.sku)
    .subscribe(res=>{
      this.sku=res;
    })
  }
  

 

  open(content: any){
    this.modalService.open(content,{ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'})
  }
}
```

I would expect the picture, not the url

Comment: use property binding for the image source `[src]="sku.imageLink"`, not string interpolation

Comment: what should i change?